# Enable deletion of files through Apache Web Directory Listing

Tags: apache

I have an Apache server with a Document Root pointing to a location on Linux file system. The directory structure is read-only right now, but I need to provide a way for specific users to either directly delete files or mark files to be deleted (where some automated process can run after words and deleted the files that have been marked as so).

The users don't have ssh access to the box and I need them to be able to do this through the web directory listing.

I should mention all this is happening behind a firewall, so disregard any security risks in your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're really asking is either:

- some file-manager web-app
- WebDAV

For filemanager there are myriads of alternatives (for example: [eXplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/), [phpFileManager](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/)

For WebDAV - you need to [enable DAV module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html) :

```
DavLockDB /usr/local/apache2/var/DavLock

<Location /foo>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Dav On

AuthType Basic
AuthName DAV
AuthUserFile user.passwd

<LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
Require user admin
</LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

then use webdav software (Windows calls it web folders AFAIR, Mac and Linux have decent native support as well).

Comment: I am aware of web file managers and WebDAV. Is there a way you know using either web servers or web file managers to allow users to set a description/ comment on a file (e.g. DELETE THIS) without actually allowing them to delete the file themeselves?

Comment: @fmanaa you did say "either ..  or .." ;) For what you're asking - to put a request for file deletion - it should be fairly trivial to write your own. As far as "out-of-the-box" solutions of that sort - I never came across one, mainly because I had no need for it.